# Adjust height of iframe correctly

Tags: css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iframe, height

I have this code:

```
 <iframe scrolling="no" src="http://www.portalminero.com/display/bols/Bolsa+de+Metales" 
style="border: 0 none; margin-left: 100px;  height: 860px;  width: 970px;"></iframe>
```

When I run it I load height I want, but I don't want to show the header of the page... just start in "Bolsa de Metales" title.. how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do that with CSS or JavaScript if the loaded page is not on your domain (cross-domain).
A simple solution could be just to add a div with a white background and add it as layer on top (positioning with css):

HTML:

```
<div id="myDiv"></div>

<iframe id="myIFrame" scrolling="no" src="http://www.portalminero.com/display/bols/Bolsa+de+Metales"></iframe>
```

CSS:

```
#myIFrame {
    border: 0;
    margin-left: 100px;
    height: 860px;
    width: 970px;
}
#myDiv {
    background-color:#fff;
    margin-left: 100px;
    width: 970px;
    height: 40px;
    position: absolute;
}
```